# vb.net split last part of the string

Tags: vb.net, string, split

net 2.0 and need to split the last / mark of the string. Currently I have a code that says `Dim test As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\Welcome"` and need a code that will split that Software\Microsoft\Windows\Welcome into two separate section at the end
So I'll have Software\Microsoft\Windows and Welcome as new strings.
I can only find things that will split the beginning from the rest like

```
Dim whole As String = "Software/Microsoft/Windows/Run"
Dim firstpart As String = whole.Substring(0, whole.IndexOf("/"))
Dim lastpart As String = whole.Substring(whole.IndexOf("/") + 1)`
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [String.LastIndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx)

```
Dim whole As String = "Software/Microsoft/Windows/Run"
Dim firstpart As String = whole.Substring(0, whole.LastIndexOf("/"))
Dim lastpart As String = whole.Substring(whole.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try splitting with '\' As your delimeter and store it as a string array. Then just grab the last element and it should be "Welcome".